# Passing array and deleting from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, html, arrays, forms

I have a table in mysql and I'm printing it on screen by this code:

```
include ('mysql_con.php');
mysql_select_db("jaz", $con);

$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hovno ORDER BY id DESC");

echo "<form action='delete_from_db.php' method='POST'>";
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td colspan='6'>" . "<input type='submit' value='Delete Article'>" . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<b>" . "Delete" . "</b>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<b>" . "ID" . "</b>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<b>" . "Date" . "</b>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<b>" . "Title" . "</b>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<b>" . "Preview" . "</b>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<b>" . "Author" . "</b>" . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
while($a=mysql_fetch_array($res1))  {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='" . $a["id"] . "'>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $a["id"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $a["created"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $a["title"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $a["preview"] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $a["author"] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
                                }
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

So I'm putting id's as checkbox values into array.
In another php file I wan't to use this id's in array to delete this records with those id's. I don't know what code to use for that buy i tried this:

```
<?php

include ('mysql_con.php');
mysql_select_db("jaz", $con) or die(mysql_error());

        $del[]=$_POST["checkbox"];

        $res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hovno WHERE id='$del'") or die(mysql_error());

    while($a = mysql_fetch_array($res1)){
            $b = $a["id"];
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM hovno WHERE id ='$b'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

?>

Any idea how to actually make it work? Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value) {

   // delete query here

}
```

Comment: you have to give where id='$value' in your delete query

Comment: This is resource hungry... if there will be 100 ids, then you're going to run 100 sql queries?

Answer (score 3):

Although I'm not sure about PHP, if you get the list of IDs, separated by commas you can use SQL operator "in". Something like this:

```
$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hovno WHERE id in (1,2,3)")
```

comment about variable names:
A jestli si ty promenne slusne nepojmenujes, tak se v tom uz nikdy nevyznas ;)

Comment: you can also use the same syntax in the DELETE query.
"DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id IN (1,2,3)"

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $del = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $idsToDelete = implode($del, ', ');
    $res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hovno WHERE id in ($idsToDelete)");
?>
```

Comment: This code has security issue - is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: @JiříHerník sure. The question is not about how to write the complete secure system, but the questions is "I have some code and it doesn't work as I want it to work, how can I fix it?".

Comment: I understand, but it is important to point out the security issue, because the asker is novice.

Comment: Should I point to poor software design issues if asker is novice?

Comment: I think, one should not make examples, which has such problems. Just use one more function, for example "addslashes" or "escape".

Comment: `addslashes` will not fix it: http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string
I guess `escape` also will not prevent all possible cases. The correct way is to filter input and escape output.